# What is wrong with my code?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def extractEachKth(inputArray, k):
    n = []
    for i in inputArray:
        n.append(i)
    for i in range(1, len(n) + 1):
        if i % k == 0:
            n.remove(n[i-1])
    return (n)
    print (extractEachKth([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3))
```

and here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/editable.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (extractEachKth([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3))
    File "C:/Users/Harry/Documents/randompythonprograms/editable.py", line 7, in extractEachKth
    n.remove(n[i-1])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Change it to `for i in range(1, len(n))`

Comment: We don't know what you want your code to do, so it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: `n.remove(n[i-1])` this is causing the problem, since you're removing values from the list and looping till `n` so it won't have same size i.e, length of the list will reduce and will give you `index out of bound error`, your range is correct

Comment: Is `return inputArray[::k]` or `return inputArray[1::k]` what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

This : `n.remove(n[i-1])` is causing the problem, since you're removing values from the list and looping till `len(n)` so it won't have same size i.e, length of the list will reduce and will give you `index out of bound error`, your range is correct.

You can solve it by updating the `N` whenever you remove a value, like this :

```
def extractEachKth(inputArray, k):
    n = []
    for i in inputArray:
        n.append(i)
    i = 1
    N = len(n) + 1
    while i < N:
        if i % k == 0:
            n.remove(n[i-1])
            N = len(n) + 1
            # or simply
            # N -= 1
        i += 1
    return (n)
print (extractEachKth([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3))
```